# Handling multiple uploaded images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, image

```
function uploadImages(uploader,callback1,callback2){
    uploader.onchange=function(){
        callback1()
        var reader=new FileReader()
        var i=0
        reader.onload=function(){
            var image=new Image()
            image.onload=callback2
            image.src=this.result
            if(++i < uploader.files.length) reader.readAsDataURL(uploader.files[i])
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(uploader.files[i])
    }
}
```

`uploader` is the `<input>` element
`callback1` is called when the user uploads something (to reset things before handling the images)
`callback2` is called once per image, when it loads.

This function is being used [here](http://12Me21.github.io/archiver/).

I feel like there might be a simpler way to do this.